# How to change language in Word 2016 template to English?

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I am using a template created by a French author in Word 2016. For documents generated with this template, **Word Options** > **Language** is English, but **Insert** > **Caption** generates French names (Tableau for Table, for example).

How can I force the template or document to be consistently in English so that I get Table instead of Tableau?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the entire document's proofing language is set to English. Remember that proofing language is set for each word, even each individual character, not for the document as a whole, so even a single character in the wrong place can throw it off.

Open the document and hit Ctrl+A to select all text and objects in the document. Then go to Review | Language | Set Proofing Language and ensure it's set to "English".

Comment: I did this accidentally yesterday after posting (trying to fix the spell check which was in French too), and when I changed to English, it asked if I wanted to change the template. So it seems to have solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

- For all documents: **Warning: this will select the default language for all your documents**. Go to Review ribbon > Language > Set Proofing Language, then select your language and click on the *Set As Default* button.
- The second option is setting the language at document level: open the *Home Ribbon* and right click in the *Normal* style, select *Modify Style*, then, with the Normal style selected, open the *Format* menu, select *Language* and select your preferred language for this document. Close the language selector and **make sure you have the "Only in this document" radio button selected**.